# Group by concat in SparkR

Tags: sparkr

I am trying to do something like group by concat in SparkR, but failed to do so.

In normal R, i am trying to do something like

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mtcars
df$text = row.names(mtcars)
result <- df %>% group_by(carb) %>% summarize(concat = paste(text, collapse = ','))
```

How could I implement this operation on a `SparkDataFrame` in `SparkR`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use sparklyr instead: http://spark.rstudio.com/ With this library you can use the `dplyr` verbs with Spark data frames.

Comment: thanks, that would do